# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in flutter

Tags: android, ios, api, flutter, dart

I'm fresh to `flutter`,  trying to create my first application that is fetching some data from an API. 
here is how the API result body looks like :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user": {
            "username": "admin@admin.com"
        },
        "name": "Ahmed Wagdi qwqw",
        "username": "admin",
        "password": "******",
        "location": {
            "user": {
                "username": "admin@admin.com"
            },
            "name": "Ahmed Wagdi",
            "phone": "01207199086",
            "latitude": "31.078221",
            "longitude": "29.734717"
        },
        "type": "Manager",
        "direct_manager": "http://g-attend.com:8000/api/panel/api/employees/1/",
        "on_duty": true
    }
]
```

And here is how am trying to call and parse it in flutter :

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';


void gettingEmployees() async{
    String url = 'http://my_url.com';
    Response response = await get(url, headers: {"Authorization":"My basic auth"});
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(data);
  }
```

And finally, I got this error :

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in flutter
```

Comment: your first byte in the response is `[` so this is a `List` not `Map` - `List data = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

into this:

```
    List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
```